# Does Admob allow placing test ads on production version of Android app

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have an android app that contains Admob ads with test ids, and i want to publish it now to production with test ids of Admob. I want to know if Google allows placing test ads on app that is available openly to everyone.

The reason i am doing this is because my app is not yet approved by Admob and i don't want to release ads-free version to production (because it contains subscription to remove ads, and i want to avoid problems in future).

I read the google policy but did not find this scenario and its solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AdMob allows you to run test ads on the production version of your Android app. Test ads are designed to help you test your app's AdMob integration without using actual ad.

To use test ads in your app, you can use test IDs provided by AdMob. These ad unit IDs will return test ads instead of live ads when your app makes an ad request. You can use test ads to verify that your app integrates well with AdMob and to make sure you're seeing the ad content you expect.

It's important to note that test ads should only be used for testing purposes not for real users. Always change test ids to real ids.